# How do I generalize the dot product (bilinear form) in spherical coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry, bilinear-form, curvilinear-coordinates

In cartesian coordinates, the unit vectors $\{u_x, u_y, u_z\}$ are universal. That is, $u_x(x, y, z)$ is constant and so on for the rest of them. Because of that, the dot product $\langle v | w \rangle$ is defined everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

But in spherical, $u_\phi(r, \phi, \theta)$ is not constant. It varies. So the dot product $\langle v | w \rangle$ is **only defined** when $u$ and $v$ share an origin.

But still, I kind of miss that old dot product. Maybe I can get a bilinear form that is defined everywhere in spherical coordinates, by doing something different. What do I need to do to get my universal bilinear form in spherical coordinates?

Comment: Even In Euclidean space, you should be taking the dot product of tangent vectors at different points. What shoukd this mean?

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I wrote my question incorrectly. I mean, at point P <v, w> is going to have one formula and at point Q != P <v, w> is going to have a differen onet. Contrast the case in cartesian coordinates where <v, w> is the same formula at all points.

Comment: Aha. Ultimately, the fact that the sphere has nonzero curvature prevents your having a coordinate system in which the inner product $g_{ij}$ is given by a constant matrix. That can happen only on a flat (locally Euclidean) space.

Comment: Can you talk more about this $g_{ij}$ thingie?